# How do class UnityEnine.Input in c# script

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have been trying to code a 3D c# game for school and I have this script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{

//Variables
public float movementSpeed;





//Functions

public float speed = 5;
public float gravity = -5;

float velocityY = 0;

CharacterController controller;

public void Start()
{
    controller = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
}

public void Update()
{
    velocityY += gravity * Time.deltaTime;

    Vector3 input = new Vector3(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal"), 0 Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical"));
    input = input.normalized;

    Vector3 temp = Vector3.zero;
    if (input.z == 1)
    {
        temp += transform.forward;
    }
    else if (input.z == -1)
    {
        temp += transform.forward * -1;
    }

    if (input.x == 1)
    {
        temp += transform.right;
    }
    else if (input.x == -1)
    {
        temp += transform.right * -1;
    }

    Vector3 velocity = temp * speed;
    velocity.y = velocityY;

    controller.Move(velocity * Time.deltaTime);

    if (controller.isGrounded)
    {
        velocityY = 0;
    }
}
}
```

So it is a script for moving the character with WASD and it has gravity but Unity is saying I need to class UnityEngine.Input interface in the input sysytem. How the heck do I do that?

Comment: I rolled back your edit. It is not proper here to add [SOLVED] to your question title. See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) to see how to properly indicate you've gotten an answer that solved the problem.

Comment: I see, okay fixed it <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you use the integrated Unity `FirstPersonController` so you don't reinvent the wheel. But if you would like to create a primitive controller you have to use `Input.GetKeyDown(yourKey)`, this will solve the problem.

Comment: Omg just realized I forgot to reply, omg I feel so bad, it worked thanks so much <3